# Understanding block structure in MIT Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, language-design, sicp, mit-scheme

Take the following function definition as my example:

```
(define (foo)
  (bar)
  (define (bar)
    (display "bar")))
```

This would produce an error: `;Premature reference to reserved name: bar`. On the contrary, the following two definitions are legitimate. Note that I'm using premature reference in both of them.

```
(define (foo)
  (bar))
(define (bar)
  (display "bar"))

(define (foo)
  (define (bar)
    (display "bar"))
  (bar))
```

My question is: why can't I prematurely reference a currently undefined function when using block structure? And why is `bar` a "reserved name"?

Comment: You can't, or at least shouldn't be able to, because internal `define`s may occur only at the beginning of the body of a `define`, `lambda`, `let`, `let*`, `letrec` etc (according to r5rs).

Comment: @manualcrank But why? Premature reference can make code more comprehensive, which I believe to be a great advantage. What are the drawbacks of allowing `define` to appear anywhere in the body of a containing `define`?

Comment: Some schemes probably do allow your first definition, but will raise an error when `bar` is invoked before its definition.

Comment: For example Racket will allow you to define `(define (foo) (bar) (define (bar) (display "bar")) (bar))`. Notice, though, the extra `(bar)` after its definition; Racket insists on at least one expression after a sequence of internal definitions.  Chez Scheme, OTOH, rejects both this and your original `foo` at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference it, but you can't *use* what's still undefined.

Racket lets you define

```
(define (foo) 
  (bar)                    ; here the future error
  (define (bar) 
      (display "bar")) 
  (bar))
```

but when you try to call `(foo)` it errors with the message

> ```
>     bar: undefined;
> cannot use before initialization
> ```

So, there *is* a certain *timeline* involved here, certain *sequencing*; some things are done before others, according to their textual position in the definition. Consider this further Racket REPL interaction:

```
> (define (foo) (baz) (define (bar) (display "bar")) (bar))
> (foo)
. . baz: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
> (define (baz) '())
> (foo)
bar
```

The REPL has its own timeline. Each Scheme implementation can handle this aspect of REPL in its own way, though.

Comment: `(define (foo)
  (bar))
(define (bar)
  (display "bar"))` In this code, it seems that the timeline is kind of chaotic: `(bar)` is referenced and called _before_ its definition. Could you explain why is it?

Comment: you have two definitions there. the first defines `foo` as calling `(bar)` -- it doesn't call it yet, just is defined to do so, *when* and *if* called in the future. If `(foo)` were indeed called next, it would error with `undefined: bar` message. Instead, the second definition defines `bar`, so after that, if `(foo)` is called, no error will be caused. --- important note: some REPLs would still make it an error -- they do not define same name `bar` that `foo` sees, but another, *newer* `bar`. That is what I hinted at in the last sentence.

Comment: so `bar` *is* referenced before it is defined, but it is *not* called (used).